# Template parse errors: Parser Error: Unexpected token 'Date'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a angular2 app with typescript. I am trying to get current time. Here is my code

```
<div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="gotoAndBot-Copy-3" >
              gotoAndBot
          <span class="-copy-2">
            {{new Date().toLocaleDateString()}}
          </span>
          </div> 
      </div>

  </div> 
</div>
```

but it complains with `Template parse errors: Parser Error: Unexpected token 'Date'`
I am wundering why it does not recognize the `Date`

so how can i fix it?

Comment: Angular 2's templating syntax does not support newing up objects (try it with any object).

If you need the date, instantiate it in the component as `currentTimeStamp = new Date().toLocaleDateString()`
and then reference currentTimeStamp in your template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't place arbitrary expressions in an Angular 2 template. Instead, you can create a member in your component called `dateString` and display that.

Try

```
@Component({
    // ...
})
export class App {
    dateString = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
}
```

with the template

```
<div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="gotoAndBot-Copy-3" >
              gotoAndBot
          <span class="-copy-2">
            {{dateString}}
          </span>
          </div> 
      </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```